# Cisco Catalyst Line Cards - memory considerations

Tags: cisco, routing, switching, cisco-catalyst

Do the Catalyst Line Cards (4500 and 6500 series) hold memory (kept after reload), or some other information independently of the Supervisor Card?
I ask regarding a chassis reset process, in order to perform it properly, to be sure to erase the information from the Supervisor and from the Line cards if necessary.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The Cisco 4500 and 6500 Series line cards only have local DRAM. If the line card is removed or powered off all the local memory is lost.

The Supervisor is the only line card component that has permanent NVRAM, that among other things holds the switch configurations.